# Apache NetBeans 11.0 Menu Bar is displaying junk text

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, encoding, netbeans

Just installed Apache NetBeans 11.0 on Windows 10. I've noticed that the menu bar text is completely messed up.

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: MenuBar]

Is this an encoding issue? How can I get around this?